# how to plot variables with possibly wild variable values?

Tags: user-interface, plot, geometry, output, reverse-engineering

I want to build an application that would do something equivalent to running lsof (maybe changing it to output differently, because string processing may mean it is not real time enough) in a loop and then associate each line (entries) with what iteration it was present in, what I will be referring further as frames, as later on it will be better for understanding. My intention with it is that showing the times in which files are open by applications can reveal something about their structure, while not having big impact on their execution, which is often a problem. One problem I have is on processing the output, which would be a table relating "frames X entry", for that I am already anticipating that I will have wildly variable entry lengths. Which can fall in that problem of representing on geometry when you have very different scales, the smaller get infinitely small, while the bigger gets giant and fragmentation makes it even worse; so my question is if plotting libraries deal with this problem and how they do it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most well-established technique for showing both small and large values in reasonable detail is a logarithmic scale. Instead of plotting raw values, plot their logarithms. This is notoriously problematic if you can have zero or even negative values, but as I understand your situations all your lengths would be strictly positive so this should work.

Another statistical solution you could apply is to plot ranks instead of raw values. Take all the observed values, and put them in a sorted list. When plotting any single data point, instead of plotting the value itself you look up that value in the list of values (possibly using binary search since it's a sorted list) then plot the index at which you found the value.

This is a monotonous transformation, so small values map to small indices and big values to big indices. On the other hand it completely discards the actual magnitude, only the relative comparisons matter.

If this is too radical, you could consider using it as an ingredient for something more tuneable. You could experiment with a linear combination, i.e. plot

```
a*x + b*log(x) + c*rank(x)
```

then tweak a, b and c till the result looks pleasing.